# Limits of discrete series.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If a sequence ${b_{n}}$ does not have a limit as n tends to infinity, can I conclude that the series takes on all values in the range of the function.

$$b_{n+1}=b_1-\frac{1}{b_n}$$

this series does not have a limit for values of $b_1$ less than $2$ so I want to know if I can conclude that this series does have negative values.

Comment: it must have a limit, it just might not converge, do you mean $b_n\to\pm\infty$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: For *general* sequences, failure to converge has no sign implications.

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence converges iff $|b_1|\ge 2$, as you have observed. If $0<|b_1|<2$, it will always take on negative values, although this is not a general fact of arbitrary sequences. If $b_1=0$, the sequence is undefined after the first term, and if $b_1<0$, then of course the sequence takes on negative values (like, say, $b_1$). So suppose $0<b_1<2$. If $b_n>0$, then $b_{n+1}-b_n=b_1-(b_n+\frac1{b_n})\le b_1-2$ (using the inequality $x+\frac1x\ge2$ which is a special case of the AM-GM inequality). Thus each step takes us uniformly closer to zero with step size $2-b_1$, so at some point (at most $n=\frac{b_1}{2-b_1}$) we must go below zero.